# UTF-8 decoding problems

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, decoding

I am getting crazy with UTF-8 decoding of some URLs. I am using

```
URLDecoder.decode (java.net.URLDecoder)
```

to decode some URLs with special chars. As you can see below for some location names in the URL the decode works and for some it does not ...

```
biha%C4%87 --> biha? (WRONG)
d%C3%A9partement+morbihan --> département morbihan (CORRECT)
gespanschaft+me%C4%91imurje --> gespanschaft me?imurje (WRONG)
hajd%C3%BA+bihar --> hajdú bihar (CORRECT)
```

Any Ideas? would highly appriciate!
Thom

Comment: PS: the URL decoder (http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) encodes correctly:
https://www.twago.de/s/freelancer/in/biha%C4%87/
-->
https://www.twago.de/s/freelancer/in/bihać/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8")` all your URLs are decoded **correctly**.

However the decoded strings of case 1 and 3 contain characters with codepoint 263 and 273.
Most likely you printed these strings to a console which cannot print characters with codepoints > 255 and which replaces those with a `?`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem :) the char encoding actually got lost on its way to the DB. So i just had to change the hibernate settings a bit and now it works! thanks for pointing me to the right solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/servlets/TestServlet?name=!\"#$%&/()=?¡áéíóú";
    String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded);
    System.out.println("Decoded: " + URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8"));
```